# How can I prevent Visual Studio Code cursor skipping symbols when using CTRL + Left/Right Arrow?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cursor, hotkeys, vscode-keybinding

From the position in my screenshot, if I do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd>, the cursor will skip the `.` symbol. Same for `={`, it will skip `=` symbol. How can I prevent this behavior in VS Code, and not skip that? In JetBrains products, it works like that, and it's really bothers me in VS Code.

[image: cursor position example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want the `cursorWordStartLeft` and `cursorWordStartRight` bindings to be bound.  You can set them to whatever you want, but you probably want them to be the same as the `cursorWordLeft` and `cursorWordRight`.  Of course you also probably want to unbind the other controls too.  You also probably want the same when condition which is `textInputFocus && !accessibilityModeEnabled`:

[image: cursor word start left and right bindings to enable]

After setting this bindings, the cursor behaves more like how you want:

[image: gif showing changed cursor beahvior]

Comment: Yes, more, but not exactly as i want to. Well, i guess VSCode just haven't this behavior yet, and not sure it'll ever have. Thanks for your answer anyways.

Answer (score 0):

There are the following keybinding commands that you can experiment with using, and tuning to your taste: `cursorWordStartLeft`, `cursorWordStartRight`, `cursorWordEndLeft`, and `cursorWordEndRight`.

There are also things like `cursorWordAccessibilityLeft` (seems to skip more), `cursorWordPartLeft` (Ex. stops at things like capitals in camel-case words), and `cursorWordPartStartLeft` that you can experiment with.

For example here's how you can unbind the default `cursorWordLeft` and `cursorWordRight` from <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd>, and instead bind them to `cursorWordStartLeft` and `cursorWordEndRight`:

```json
// unbind defaults:
{
    "key": "ctrl+left",
    "command": "-cursorWordLeft",
    "when": "textInputFocus"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+right",
    "command": "-cursorWordRight",
    "when": "textInputFocus"
},
```

And then,

```json
// bind customizations:
{
    "key": "ctrl+left",
    "command": "cursorWordStartLeft",
    "when": "textInputFocus"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+right",
    "command": "cursorWordEndRight",
    "when": "textInputFocus"
},
```

Or perhaps you instead want it the other way around:

```json
// bind customizations:
{
    "key": "ctrl+left",
    "command": "cursorWordEndLeft",
    "when": "textInputFocus"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+right",
    "command": "cursorWordStartRight",
    "when": "textInputFocus"
},
```

Note also that there is a `editor.wordSeparators` that controls what characters are treated as word separators, which you can also set on a per-language basis.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Thats not exactly what i want, but close to.